# Finite Measure Space: Integral Closure = Bochner Integral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, lebesgue-integral

*I can't sleep for so long time as the integral gives me headaches.

I was looking for so many approaches. Now another one. Hope this works...*

Let $\Omega$ be a finite measure space and $E$ a Banach space.
Consider the function space $\mathcal{F}(\Omega,E)$ with the topology of $\mu$-almost everywhere convergence.
Define the integral of a a simple function $s=\sum_i a_i \chi_{A_i}$ as $I(s):=\sum_i a_i\mu(A_i)$.

Is the operator closable, i.e.:
$$(s_n,I(s_n))\to(0,c)\implies(c=0)$$
(Note that the measure space is finite $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$, so there can't be running blocks to infinity...)

Moreover does the closure coincide with the Bochner integral?

Comment: Quick comment: Under most circumstances (e.g. Lebesgue measure on the unit interval), pointwise convergence is **not** given by a topology. One way to see this is that there are sequences $(f_n)_n$ and $f$ so that every subsequence $(f_{n_k})_k$ has a further subsequence $(f_{n_{k_\ell}})_\ell$ converging to $f$ without having $f_n \to f$.

Comment: I wasn't so clear about that -my fault- but what I meant is the topology induced by the seminorms $p_\omega(f)=|f(\omega)|$ for $\omega\in\Omega$. However for the purpose here it would be blown up to consider these  aspects, but thanks for the comment ;)

Comment: Or did I miss sth in your comment?

Comment: Okay, you can consider this topology, but this is the topology of pointwise convergence, **not** of convergence $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok to bad, the answer is again: No!

For $s_n:=n\chi_{[0,\frac{1}{n}]}$ it follows $s_n\to 0$ but $I(s_n)\to 1$.